# Content inside of scrollable div, causing a page scrollbar in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to incorporate sticky headers into my company's internal data table component. The best way I've gotten it to work (with Chrome), while not screwing up any other features is generating something like this:

```
<table class="headers">
    <thead> // ... header stuff</thead>
    <tbody> // ... body stuff</tbody>
</table>
<div class="scrollBody">
    <table class="headers">
        <thead> // ... header stuff</thead>
        <tbody> // ... body stuff</tbody>
    </table>
</table>
```

and css like so:

```
th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.headers tbody {
    visibility: collapse;
}
.scrollBody thead {
    visibility: collapse;
}
.scrollBody {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This works exactly as wanted in Chrome. It displays a table with headers and a scrollbar that scrolls the table body. In IE, however, it looks correct, until you realize that the page now has 2 scrollbars. One next to the table body (as expected) and the page itself has one.

Here is a link to a codepen: https://codepen.io/petetalksweb2/pen/WyeaWL?editors=1100

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround it with a `div` with `overflow: hidden;`

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/pen/oyvJga?editors=1100)

Comment: Works great! Thanks!